# What is a more concise way to initialize constant variable when more than two values are possible

Tags: javascript, typescript

Title says it all. I'm looking for a more elegant way to declare and assign constant variable using a conditional statement than this:

```
const someVar = (() => {
    switch (otherVar) {
        case someVal: return something
        case otherVal: return somethingElse
        default: return somethingDefault
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the logic into a method and use an object, which looks similar to your initial code:

```
const getValue = key => {
  return {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz',
    baz: 'quux',
  }[key] || 'defaultValue'
}

const someVar = getValue(otherVar)
```

Which can be further simplified, though whether it's more readable is debatable

```
const getValue = key => ({
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'baz',
  baz: 'quux',
}[key] || 'defaultValue')

const someVar = getValue(otherValue)
```

You could still immediately invoke the function if you wanted, but by extracting the logic into a method it can be used elsewhere and ease testing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using ternary operator.

```js
const someVar = ((otherVar) => {
    return (otherVar == "someVal")? "something": (otherVar == "otherVal")? "somethingElse": "somethingDefault";

})("someVal")

console.log(someVar);
```